# Solve IAP pending transaction using price point in iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm building a cross-platform library which surface In-App Purchase as a feature.

Some users are using the multiple price point technique in order to make their content management more flexible.
In a few words, they setup price points in the App Store dashboard:

- `com.mygame.small-product`
- `com.mygame.medium-product`
- `com.mygame.big-product`

Then they store the configuration of the pack, and associating it to a price point.

```js
{
  "key": "my-pack",
  "apple-product-id": "com.mygame.small-product",
  "google-product-id": "com.mygame.small-product",
  "rewards":
  [
    { "itemId": "bla", "amount": 42 }
  ]
}
```

On Android, in order to support pending transactions, we inject the `key` of the pack to the payload of the purchase request, so in case of a crash, when we get the pending transaction back (when the app starts), we have the `key` of the pack and its platform store `product id` so we can finish the purchase process for the proper pack.

I didn't find anything alike in the iOS API.
So I wonder how you guys are dealing with this aspect of the purchase process in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% following the use case, but as soon as you begin a transaction on iOS, you will get the appropriate state callbacks on the payment queue https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/1506107-paymentqueue

It's imperative you add yourself as an observer to the payment queue on app launch. So if your app crashes during a payment (I can't see why but...), then when the app is opened once more, you add yourself as an observer in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions AppDelegate method. Then the observer will immediately callback with the current payment state, which could consist of the following states: purchasing, purchased, failed, restored, or deferred
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionstate

This callback will contain the product_id - so the product the user is purchasing, but won't contain any pricing information.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, and thanks for your answer.
`product_id` is the `id` of the product in Apple's dashboard, not the `id` of the pack in my game.
So it will be `com.mygame.small-product` and not `my-pack`, according to my example.

The problem I am trying to solve is how to know which pack I try to buy, as the `product_id` linked to this pack can be used in mulitple packs.